# mootools 1.4.2 and angular 1.3 playing nicely together in ie8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, mootools

I have a shimmed and polyfilled version of angularjs 1.3 working perfectly on ie8.  Unfortunately when mootools is included on the page there are quite a few conflicts.  I have managed to get a handle on all but one with the following which adds add / remove EventListener and dispatchEvent to Window.prototype, HTMLDocument.prototype and Element.prototype.  It checks to see if mootools is loaded and if so it adds them differently.

```
!window.addEventListener && (function (WindowPrototype, DocumentPrototype, ElementPrototype, addEventListener, removeEventListener, dispatchEvent, registry) {
        var addEventListenerFn = function(type, listener) {
            var target = this;
            registry.unshift([target, type, listener,
                function (event) {
                    event.currentTarget = target;
                    event.preventDefault = function () {
                        event.returnValue = false;
                    };
                    event.stopPropagation = function () {
                        event.cancelBubble = true;
                    };
                    event.target = event.srcElement || target;
                    listener.call(target, event);
                }]);

            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
            if (type === 'load' && this.tagName && this.tagName === 'SCRIPT') {
                var reg = registry[0][3];
                this.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
                    if (this.readyState === "loaded" || this.readyState === "complete") {
                        reg.call(this, {
                            type: "load"
                        });
                    }
                }
            } else {
                this.attachEvent('on' + type, registry[0][3]);
            }
        };

        var removeEventListenerFn = function(type, listener) {
            for (var index = 0, register; register = registry[index]; ++index) {
                if (register[0] == this && register[1] == type && register[2] == listener) {
                    if (type === 'load' && this.tagName && this.tagName === 'SCRIPT') {
                        this.onreadystatechange = null;
                    }

                    return this.detachEvent('on' + type, registry.splice(index, 1)[0][3]);
                }
            }
        };

        var dispatchEventFn = function(eventObject) {
            return this.fireEvent('on' + eventObject.type, eventObject);
        };

        if(Element.prototype.$constructor && typeof Element.prototype.$constructor === 'function') {
            Element.implement(addEventListener, addEventListenerFn);
            Element.implement(removeEventListener, removeEventListenerFn);
            Element.implement(dispatchEvent, dispatchEventFn);
            Window.implement(addEventListener, addEventListenerFn);
            Window.implement(removeEventListener, removeEventListenerFn);
            Window.implement(dispatchEvent, dispatchEventFn);
        } else {
            WindowPrototype[addEventListener] = ElementPrototype[addEventListener] = addEventListenerFn;
            WindowPrototype[removeEventListener] = ElementPrototype[removeEventListener] = removeEventListenerFn;
            WindowPrototype[dispatchEvent] = ElementPrototype[dispatchEvent] = dispatchEventFn;
        }
        DocumentPrototype[addEventListener] = addEventListenerFn;
        DocumentPrototype[removeEventListener] = removeEventListenerFn;
        DocumentPrototype[dispatchEvent] = dispatchEventFn;
    })(Window.prototype, HTMLDocument.prototype, Element.prototype, 'addEventListener', 'removeEventListener', 'dispatchEvent', []);
```

This has resolved all my errors bar one.  When this function is called in Angular, when mootools is on the page, and element is a form addEventListener is undefined.

```
addEventListenerFn = function(element, type, fn) {
      element.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
    }
```

specifically this function is called from angulars formDirective like so

```
addEventListenerFn(formElement[0], 'submit', handleFormSubmission);
```

Any ideas why the form element still dosn't have the addEventListener function available?

Comment: Why `Element.implement(addEventListener, addEventListenerFn);`? why not using MooTools `addEvent`?

Comment: well angular calls addEventListener not addEvent and I would prefer to get as close to the native implementations as possible wherever possible.  I dont really want to have anything to do with the mootools code

Comment: erm. in IE8, there are problems with extending the Element prototype. The DOM API is touch and go, it's exposed to a degree but there are non-available props and lack of spec. MooTools addresses this via copying the methods onto elements objects directly when you pass them through `$` / `document.id`. you may be able to add to `HTMLFormElement.prototype` direct in IE8 but no promises. http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/ is a decent read. Another solution for you would be to wrap element in $ but that is crap. (`$(element).addEventListener(type, fn, false);`).

Comment: also, Angular 1.3.x is no longer 'supporting' IE8. because hipster kiddies who write it don't care about real world projects and use.

Comment: yes that sucks but due to the work of this guy https://github.com/fergaldoyle/angular.js-ie8-builds angular core still works great in ie8......just not with mootools on the page at the same time :p  We have a requirement to support ie8 for another while yet so trying to find a way to upgrade but still support ie8.  This use case where mootools is also on the page is an edge case in our situation but it needs to work

Comment: @DimitarChristoff HTMLFormElement.prototype gets rid of the error for me if youw ant to make it an answer I will except it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending native type via `Element.prototype` in IE8 is considered very unreliable as the prototype is only partially exposed and certain things are not inheriting from it / misbehave.

http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

What MooTools does in this case is rather than work around the quirks of all edgecases that don't adhere to the correct proto chain (and because of IE6/7 before that) is to COPY the Element prototypes on the objects of the DOM nodes as you pass it through the `$` selector.

This is not ideal, because.

```
var foo = document.id('foo'); 
// all known methods from Element.prototype are copied on foo, which now hasOwnProperty for them
Element.prototype.bar = function(){};
foo.bar(); // no own property bar, going up the chain may fail dependent on nodeType
```

Anyway, that aside - you can fix your particular problem by copying your methods from the `Element.prototype` to the special `HTMLFormElement.prototype` - any any other elements constructors you may find to differ.

It's not scalable, you may then get an error in say `HTMLInputElement` and so forth, where do you draw the line?